# Foundation 6 - Use CSS to arrange Header image and Nav properly

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, nav, zurb-foundation-6

I am using Foundation 6 to try to create **a header image which overlaps part of a navigation bar**. It uses the `.row` class as a responsive div.

**HTML**

```
<header class="row text-center">
  <a href="//google.com">
    <img src="path/to/horizontal banner image">
  </a>
 </header>

<nav>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <a href="//yahoo.com">Text here</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
header{
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

nav{
  margin-top: -5%;
  font-size: 150%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvmt2j1j/

As illustrated in the above fiddle, I have an image and a nav bar that includes links. The image itself is a link too.

However I found out that:

- when the screen size is large, the text goes upward and does not not
  align with the image properly anymore.
- In some browsers the image link overlaps the nav bar link. I would like to restrict the clickable area of the image to the green area only.

I am quite new to this, therefore I believe there is probably a better way to structure the `<div>` tags or CSS to achieve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My proposition:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #6C6;
  background-image: url("http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/imagecache/middle/banner_white.png"), url("https://i.imgur.com/TILTsNC.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
  background-position: top center, bottom;
  height: 189px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 550px;
}
.green {
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
}
.blue {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="green" href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
  <a class="blue" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">Text here</a>
</header>
```

You define a header with just two `<a>` elements that you treat as block (*flow* in HTML5) content, meaning they will behave just like `div`s, but will be clickable of course, because they are still links after all. To do so, you got to give them `display: block` style. Then you need to stack two backgrounds for `<header>`. First one is your picture and the second one is lightblue color with width of 1px and height of desired blue area height (in this case 20% of 189px). More info on *[Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)* (MDN).

Comment: However what I want is part of the image covers the nav bar.  That's why I included a 'margin-top: -5%;' but found out those issues I mentioned in the question. In your example, if you use 'margin-top: -5%;' on .blue, the blue background color covers the image.

Comment: Thank you. However, since I am using Foundation as the css framework as mentioned above, there any way to achieve a responsive one? That is, the image will resize according to browser window size (try to resize the image in the fiddle).